# how to get VLOOKUP value from another workbook?

Tags: vba

Below code is working good with same workbook. But when  I am trying to get VLOOKUP value from another workbook, it is not getting the value.

```
        Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
        Dim rngCell As Range, m1 As Variant ', m2 As Variant
        On Error GoTo Hello:
        If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C100001")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        
        For Each rngCell In Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C100001"))
            If Len(rngCell.Value) > 0 Then
    
'This line is working good
               'm1 = Application.VLookup(rngCell.Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AllVehicleNumbers").Range("B2:C100001"), 2, False)
    
'But this is not working
                m1 = Application.VLookup(rngCell.Value, Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\VehicleNumbers.xlsx").Worksheets("AllVehicleNumbers").Range("B2:C100001"), 2, False)
    
                If Not IsError(m1) Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    rngCell.Value = m1
                      
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            End If
        Next
        
        Hello:
        End Sub
```

Comment: The other workbook needs to be open for that to work, and just use the filename, not the full path.

Comment: Sir, I have tried but nothing happened. and required the workbook closed.

Comment: If you use VLOOKUP in a cell it should work with the workbook closed, but I don't think it can work when used in VBA.

Comment: Another workbook is open but still does not happened anything.

Comment: Comment out the error handler and see if anything changes

Comment: Add Option Explicit and remove all error handling

Comment: I follow your instructions. (with or without full path of file) now it is says workbook not found. and just opens relevant workbook but does not give VLOOKUP value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work on a closed workbook:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim c As Range, rng As Range, v, frm

    On Error GoTo haveError
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C2:C100001"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'Note your formula will vary a little if you're looking up numeric values
    '  (no quotes around the lookup value)
    frm = "=VLOOKUP(""<v>"",'" & ThisWorkbook.Path & _
            "\[VehicleNumbers.xlsx]AllVehicleNumbers'!B2:C100001,2,FALSE)"
    
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            c.Formula = Replace(frm, "<v>", v)
            c.Calculate
            If IsError(c.Value) Then
                c.Value = v  'no match - replace the original value
                c.Font.Color = vbRed 'flag no match
            Else
                c.Value = c.Value      'convert to value
                c.Font.Color = vbBlack 'clear any flag
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    Next
    Exit Sub
    
haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect Sir, No Doubt you are a genius. You made my day. Thank You Very Very Much.